# Can't drop HTML Element in IE 10

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-10

I'm implementing a document management system with some drag and drop organizing capabilities.

This [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop) of drag and drop works perfectly fine in IE10.

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

However, when I have very similar code I see a crossed red circle when I hover a dragged object over the `div` I want to drop into:

```
<div class="folderHeader" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">&nbsp;</div>
```

I've created a representative [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehulburd/D4fwD/).  Notice that the `allowDrop`function is not called on the `folderHeader`'s in IE (just the button elements within them).  Alternatively, the function is called on the whole `folderHeader` div in Chrome and FF.

Please note: I know the functions in the fiddle don't do anything useful.  I just want them to be properly called.

Anyone have suggestions of where I can start to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post your code, or even a sample showing the same problem? http://jsfiddle.net and http://jsbin.com can be good places use

Comment: @Slace, I've set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehulburd/D4fwD/).  LMK if you see something obvious.